# How to receive certain size of data in socket programming?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm writing a function to read from socket and return exact size of data. And I thought of codes like:

```
whlie len(buf) < required:
    buf += socket.recv(required - len(buf))

return buf
```

But I think this might waste some CPU resources(not sure). I'm looking for a system call or something to return exact amount of data from socket, and it could be blocked until the required size is received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not waste CPU resources.

`sock.recv` will [block](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking) until at least one byte is available (but may buffer and return multiple bytes if they are available), so your application will not enter a busy loop.

In general, the buffer length of the `sock.recv` call [should not have anything to do with the length of the message you'd like to retrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into).

---

String concatenation is not efficient for your buffer though.

You may want to consider using:

- A list, and `''.join()` (`b''.join()` if using Python 3)
- The `StringIO` and `cStringIO` modules (or `io.BytesIO` if using Python 3).
- Using [`sock.recv_into`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into) and `StringIO` / `bytesIO` .

Comment: Thanks for the note, I'm actually using `bytearray` type, http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html

Comment: `StringIO` and `''` are out of place here, you want [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) or `b''`.

Comment: @phihag Thanks! I keep getting bit by Python 3! : )

Comment: [socket.makefile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) is another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default socket library you can use the following.

```
import socket
host, port = "localhost", 8000
num_bytes  = 5000

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((host, port))
while True:
    data = sock.recv(num_bytes)
    handle(data)
```

You can take a look at the possible parameters here [socket.recv documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv)

Comment: This may not always work: `num_bytes` is the maximum number of bytes you will read, but may return less bytes than you intended to.

Answer (score 0):

See my example for Python 2.x socket module. Use `memoryview()` and `recv_into()`,

```
def readReliably(s,n):
    buf = bytearray(n)
    view = memoryview(buf)
    sz = s.recv_into(view,n)
    return sz,buf

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
...
sz,buf = io.readReliably(s,4)
a = struct.unpack("4B",buf)
print repr(a)
```

Size of the buffer returned by `readReliably()` can be greater than `n`, don't forget about it.