# How can I reliably read exactly n bytes from a TCP socket?

Tags: python, sockets

Context:

It is common that a binary protocol defines *frames* of a given size. The `struct` module is good at parsing that, provided everything has been received in a single buffer.

Problem:

TCP sockets are streams. A read from a socket cannot give more bytes than requested but **can** return less. So this code is not reliable:

```
def readnbytes(sock, n):
    return sock.recv(n)   # can return less than n bytes
```

The naive workaround:

```
def readnbytes(sock, n):
    buff = b''
    while n > 0:
        b = sock.recv(n)
        buff += b
        if len(b) == 0:
            raise EOFError          # peer socket has received a SH_WR shutdown
        n -= len(b)
    return buff
```

may not be efficient, because if we ask a large number of bytes, and the data if very fragmented, we will repeatedly  re-allocate a new byte buffer.

Question:

How is it possible to reliably receive exactly n bytes from a stream socket with no risk of re-allocation?

References:

Those other questions are related, and do give hints, but none give a simple and clear answer:

- [How to receive certain size of data in socket programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17508741/3545273)
- [How do I use ctypes to recv_into a C buffer multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42255313/3545273)

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15964489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [socket.makefile()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) to wrap the socket in a file-like object.  Then reads will return exactly the amount requested, unless the socket is closed where it can return the remainder.  Here's an example:

**server.py**

```
from socket import *

sock = socket()
sock.bind(('',5000))
sock.listen(1)
with sock:
    client,addr = sock.accept()
    with client, client.makefile() as clientfile:
        while True:
            data = clientfile.read(5)
            if not data: break
            print(data)
```

**client.py**

```
from socket import *
import time

sock = socket()
sock.connect(('localhost',5000))
with sock:
    sock.sendall(b'123')
    time.sleep(.5)
    sock.sendall(b'451234')
    time.sleep(.5)
    sock.sendall(b'51234')
```

**Server Output**

> ```
> 12345
> 12345
> 1234
> ```

Comment: Where is it documented that `clientfile.read(5)` reads exactly 5 bytes? In the `socket` docks, it says `makefile` will return a file object. In the python glossary, it says a "file object" is "An object exposing a file-oriented API (with methods such as read() or write())". It also says "Their interfaces are defined in the io module." In the stdlib `io` module, it says "IOBase does not declare read() or write() because their signatures will vary". Several of the `IOBase` subclasses described in the io module say `read(size=-1)` will read "*up to* `size` bytes"....

Comment: [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) says: "Fewer than size bytes may be returned if the operating system call returns fewer than size bytes.".  For file-like objects that normally happens only if EOF (or socket close/shutdown) has occurred, but if worried about it check the return value.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to use [`recv_into`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv_into) and a `memoryview`. Python allows to pre-allocate a modifiable `bytearray` that can be passed to `recv_into`. But you cannot receive data into a slice of the bytearray, because the slice would be a copy. But a `memoryview` allows to recieve multiple fragments into the same `bytearray`:

```
def readnbyte(sock, n):
    buff = bytearray(n)
    pos = 0
    while pos < n:
        cr = sock.recv_into(memoryview(buff)[pos:])
        if cr == 0:
            raise EOFError
        pos += cr
    return buff
```

Answer (score 3):

A minor addition to @Serge's answer which returns an `IncompleteReadError` (which is a subclass of `EOFError`). This contains a `partial` attribute containing the partially read data.

```
import socket
from asyncio import IncompleteReadError
 
def readexactly(sock: socket.socket, num_bytes: int) -> bytes:
    buf = bytearray(num_bytes)
    pos = 0
    while pos < num_bytes:
        n = sock.recv_into(memoryview(buf)[pos:])
        if n == 0:
            raise IncompleteReadError(bytes(buf[:pos]), num_bytes)
        pos += n
    return bytes(buf)
```

Usage:

```
try:
    print(readexactly(sock, 26))
except IncompleteReadError as e:
    print(f"Only read {len(e.partial)} out of {e.expected} bytes. :(")
    print(e.partial)
```

Example output upon only reading 5 bytes `b"ABCDE"`:

```
Only read 5 out of 26 bytes. :(
b'ABCDE'
```

Comment: Bonus: a buffered line-reader: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65637828/365102