# Python decode() 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am building this socket application and every time I am getting the following error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Here are the relevant lines from the server:

```
    filename = client_sock.recv(1024).decode()
    filesize = client_sock.recv(1024).decode()
```

Here are the relevant lines from the client:

```
    self.sock.send(file_dir.encode())
    self.sock.send(str(filesize).encode())
```

The error message happens on the second line of the server. (filesize =)
Here are prints showing what the client will send to the server.

```
    print(file_dir) # Output is D:/Statispic2/Photos/photo3.jpg
    print(filesize) # Output is 96523
```

This error only happens sometimes which is really weird. I have looked at other questions that asked a similar question but their solutions either didn't work or weren't relevant.

If you want to see the whole code or have any more questions please let me know!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The errors happen because that byte cannot be decoded to utf-8, you can handle that as exception in, with decode it as 'utf-16' on exception handling:

```
filename = client_sock.recv(1024)
filesize = client_sock.recv(1024)
try:
    decoded_filename = filename.decode()
    decoded_filesize = filename.decode()
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    decoded_filename = filename.decode('utf-16')
    decoded_filesize = filename.decode('utf-16')
```

Alternatively, you can ignore exceptions during decoding, but it's not recommended way...

```
filename = client_sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
filesize = client_sock.recv(1024).decode("utf-8", "ignore")
```

Comment: Hi I have tried doing what you have said but getting the following error from this line:
filename = client_sock.recv(1024).decode('utf-16')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 16-17: illegal encoding

Comment: need some samples of you bytes strings to reproduce it

Comment: what would happen if I would ignore them. It would probably be the incorrect string right?

Comment: you ignore characters  which cannot be decoded to utf 8, all the reset will be correctly decoded

Comment: when I use the ignore param I get ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: it's a really long string I don't think I can put it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213940/discussion-between-tomer-cahal-and-andriy-ivaneyko).

Comment: Here is a link to a google docs file containing the encoded messages that are being sent to the server.
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pjVEy72xTigazaDzNLrJ8B7vAHynC-chWGXjNV3qDm4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Your method of reading in data is unreliable, so you're probably reading more data than you want in the first `recv` and getting non-character data in the second receive. TCP is a streaming protocol, just because you send two strings in separate `send()` calls does not mean the receiver will get them in separate `recv()` calls.

If you are sending distinct pieces of data you must have some method of knowing when one piece ends and the next piece begins. The rules for your solution constitute a protocol.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814032/238704) and others for reliably reading in exactly K bytes. This may be useful if your protocol prefixes each piece with the length of that piece.

Comment: Hi man I still get the UnicodeDecodeError when sending the file size. I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Maybe I can send you the code files and you can take a look?

Comment: I don't understand because if I send the size beforehand then that would also result in two sends one after the other

Comment: The number of sends is irrelevant. What matters is recv-ing the bytes you need and no others.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issue. I just removed `.decode()` and I got appropirate results, so in your case:

```
    self.sock.send(file_dir)
    self.sock.send(str(filesize))
```