# How to prevet socket from combining data

Tags: python, json, sockets, dictionary, networking

Something that I have found very annoying is that if I were to use `conn.send()` twice before using `conn.recv()`, The data I send will be combined. Consider the following code:

```py
#server.py
...
conn.send(b'Hello')
conn.send(b'Hello')
```

```py
#client.py
sleep(5)
data = conn.recv(2048)
print(data)
```

```
#output
b'HelloHello'
```

How can I prevent this? This is mainly a big deal because I am using json to send dictionaries, and when the data is combined I get a json decode error.

Comment: You cannot prevent this when using SOCK_STREAM. That is what the STREAM part means in SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Is there a way around it? An alternative to SOCK_STREAM?

Comment: You can use SOCK_DGRAM which will use UDP, but then you lose all the substantial benefits of TCP. You can define a simple protocol on top of TCP to prefix every message with its length, using 4 or 8 bytes. Then use a proper receive loop to read the data in, such as some of the example in [an a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814032/238704).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks. In the answers you gave, each function had a param called 'size'. Would you be willing to explain why, and how I would know what to set it as when I call the function?

Comment: The code are just examples illustrating a proper read loop, `size` is the number of bytes that must be read in.

Comment: @LD Are you just planning to send strings or some binary data ?

Comment: @MohithReddy I am using json to encode dictionaries into strings (json), then encoding it into bytes.

Comment: @LD Encoding json into strings is understandable, but what do you mean to encode json into bytes ? And by doing that if you are making json data, architecture specific you should restrain yourself from doing that, instead why cant you directly transfer json in string format and generate back the dictionary at the client side.

Comment: When I try to send strings of socket I get an error saying I can only use bytes, not strings. @MohithReddy

Comment: @LD which function complaints that ? `send()` at the server side or json decoder at the client side ?

Comment: @MohithReddy `sendall()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215024/discussion-between-mohith-reddy-and-l-d).