# How to make socket.recv(x_bytes) return exactly x_bytes no more no less

Tags: python, sockets

I'm using Python 3 but assume Python 2 would work similarly

I want to have a python TCP socket receive exactly x_bytes.

```
msg = sock.recv(x_bytes)
```

This returns no more than x_bytes but may return less.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830689/10534730 suggests to use `recv(x_bytes, socket.MSG_WAITALL)` but notes that it only seems to work on Unix. I am on Windows.

Comment: See the top voted answer then, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708835/python-socket-receive-incoming-packets-always-have-a-different-size/1806965#1806965, and also follow the link (ActiveState recipes should be applicable for Windows too)

Comment: Here is an old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56814032/238704

Comment: You can't. You just have to keep calling it until you get enough bytes.